# How to write a single query using group by to attain the following output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have my own app which calculates the total amount spent at different modes of payment. The database to store the data is as follows

[image: click here to see the database snapshot]

the table create query:

```
CREATE TABLE details
(ID int,
 Fname VARCHAR(255), 
 Lname VARCHAR(255), 
 AmountSpentViaPaytm DECIMAL(10,2), 
 AmountSpentViaGpay DECIMAL(10,2),  
 AmountSpentViaNetB DECIMAL(10,2), 
 AmountSpentViaMobileB DECIMAL(10,2), 
 PaymentType VARCHAR(255), 
 MobileType VARCHAR(255), 
 PRIMARY KEY(ID));
```

the sample Insert query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE details VALUES(1, A, A, 350.00, null, null, null, PAYTM, android);
INSERT INTO TABLE details VALUES(1, B, B, null, 3000.00, null, null, GPAY, android);
```

I want the output something like this:

```
TotalAmountSpentViaPaytmInAndroid   350.00                   
CountOfRowsInPaytmInAndroid          1                         
TotalAmountSpentViaPaytmInIphone    450.00                               
CountOfRowsInPaytmInIphone           1                              
TotalAmountSpentViaGpayInAndroid    4500.00                                 
CountOfRowsInGpayInAndroid           2                             
TotalAmountSpentViaGpayInIphone      0.00                             
CountOfRowsInGpayInIphone            0                             
TotalAmountSpentViaNetBInAndroid    4000.00                             
CountOfRowsInNetBInAndroid           1                              
TotalAmountSpentViaNetBInIphone     7400.00                             
CountOfRowsInNetBInIphone            2                             
TotalAmountSpentViaMobileBInAndroid 4600.00                             
CountOfRowsInMobileBInAndroid        1                             
TotalAmountSpentViaMobileBInIphone   0.00                             
CountOfRowsInPMobileBInIphone        0
```

```
basically, I want the output as:
1. total number of people who payed using paymenttype paytm and mobile type android.
2. total number of people who payed using paymenttype paytm and mobile type iphone.
3. total number of people who payed using paymenttype gpay and mobile type android.
4. total number of people who payed using paymenttype gpay and mobile type iphone.
goes on ...

5. total amount paid via the paymenttype paytm and mobile type android.
6. total amount paid via the paymenttype paytm and mobile type iphone.
7. total amount paid via the paymenttype gpay and mobile type android.
8. total amount paid via the paymenttype gpay and mobile type iphone.
goes on...
```

I need to use a single query to get all these data since multiple queries become
a load to the backend because of the size of the database.
I have tried using the group by statement but I am not able to find a solution
to the above mentioned problem with a single query.

The command I tried is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), PaymentType, MobileType
from details
group by PaymentType, MobileType;
```

Output is something like this:

```
count(*),paymentType,MobileType
1,PAYTM, android
1,PAYTM, iphone
2, GPAY, android
goes on...
```

Comment: And please **do not** [delete your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67698645/i-want-to-write-a-single-sql-code-by-grouping-two-columns) and then open a new account just to ask the same question again. Clarify the original question.

Comment: @DaleK had to delete the previous question. I am new to the platform so I am unaware of the norms. I will update the tried methods.

Comment: "Had to delete the previous question."?? How come? I don't know of any circumstance where you *have* to delete your question.

Comment: @DaleK I got a comment saying closing the post since the format of the question is not valid.

Comment: Even if that were the case (which seems unlikely), you shouldn't create a new account.

Comment: @DaleK I won't repeat the same mistake again. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table structure seems a bit strange.  Since you already have the payment type and from what I can see only one payment type per line can exist I would expect there to be one column for spend if that were the case it could be simply grouped by the PaymentType and MobileType.

```
SELECT PaymentType, MobileType,  COUNT(*) CountOfRows, Sum(spend) Spent
from details
group by PaymentType, MobileType;
```

But since you have multiple columns we can just add them together before doing the sum.

```
SELECT PaymentType, MobileType, COUNT(*) CountOfRows,
  Sum(coalesce(AmountSpentViaPaytm, 0) + 
   coalesce(AmountSpentViaGpay, 0) + 
   coalesce(AmountSpentViaNetB, 0) + 
   coalesce(AmountSpentViaMobileB, 0)) Spent
FROM details
GROUP BY PaymentType, MobileType;
```

This won't give you the text output that you initially asked for but it will present the information in a way that is easy to read/interpret.  You could then use a presentation layer to present it (excel, SSRS, etc.)